# In a dataframe, how can i find if each row number appears in a column of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame, I need to create a new column 'flag' which will have value True in row `i` if `i` is not in any of the lists in column 'id' and False otherwise.

For the example below, flag for rows 1, 3, 5, and 6 should be True.
I attempt it with lambda, but cannot get it work.

```
import pandas as pd

pos = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'pred'])
pos.loc[1,'id'] = [4, 4]
pos.loc[2,'id'] = [2]
pos.loc[3,'id'] = [2, 4]
pos.loc[4,'id'] = [2]
pos.loc[5,'id'] = [2, 4]
pos.loc[6,'id'] = [4]
for i in range(0, len(pos)):
    pos['flag'] = pos.apply(lambda x: int(i in x['id']), axis=True)

print(pos)
```

```
     id pred   flag
1  [4, 4]  NaN  False
2     [2]  NaN  False
3  [2, 4]  NaN  False
4  [2, 6]  NaN  False
5  [2, 6]  NaN  False
6     [6]  NaN  False
```

Comment: how does your input df pos exactly look like?

Comment: What's the question? Do you want help with debugging your code, or are you looking for a solution ignoring your code? Check out [ask] for tips.

Comment: Also, beside the point, but why are you creating your df like that? If you have the data ahead of time, you can just feed it into the df constructor, then you get the correct dtypes.

Comment: Either helping with my code or an alternative solution would work. I don't have data ahead of time. This is a subproblem for a much bigger task that I actually have where the df is created dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With (`~`)[`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
pos["flag"] = ~pos.index.isin(pos["id"].explode()) # .astype(int) ?
```

Output :

```
       id pred   flag
1  [4, 4]  NaN   True
2     [2]  NaN  False
3  [2, 4]  NaN   True
4     [2]  NaN  False
5  [2, 4]  NaN   True
6     [4]  NaN   True

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. will it run explode function pos["id"] column for every row? Is this the optimal solution?

Comment: @K.Oleksy No, `pos["id"].explode()` is evaluated only once.

Comment: @K.Oleksy Regarding the "optimal solution", it depends how you quantify it. `.isin(<Series>)` is *O(n)*, but I posted a version using `.isin(<set>)` that's *O(1)* (in general), but that doesn't matter if the df is never very large. (**edit**: tangent: `.isin(<categorical Series>)` might be optimized to be *O(m)* where *m* is the number of categories, but IDK - just thinking.)

Answer (score 3):

We can compile column `id` into a set:

```
ids = {e for v in pos['id'] for e in v}
```

```
{2, 4}
```

Then it's as simple as checking (not) [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) on the index:

```
pos['flag'] = ~pos.index.isin(ids)
```

```
       id pred   flag
1  [4, 4]  NaN   True
2     [2]  NaN  False
3  [2, 4]  NaN   True
4     [2]  NaN  False
5  [2, 4]  NaN   True
6     [4]  NaN   True
```

Or all in one line:

```
pos['flag'] = ~pos.index.isin({e for v in pos['id'] for e in v})
```

The advantage over [exploding](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) `pos['id']` is that you don't have a possibly large intermediate value due to duplicates. The set will only be as big as the number of *unique* elements.

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer, I agree that set operations are probably ideal here

Answer (score 2):

Variant from @Timeless' approach but using a set union:

```
pos['flag'] = ~pos.index.isin(set().union(*pos['id']))
```

Output:

```
       id pred   flag
1  [4, 4]  NaN   True
2     [2]  NaN  False
3  [2, 4]  NaN   True
4     [2]  NaN  False
5  [2, 4]  NaN   True
6     [4]  NaN   True
```

Comment: Nice! I knew there was a more elegant way to write it than I did :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def rowIndex(row):
    return row.name not in unique_values

unique_id_values = pos["id"].explode().unique()
pos['flag'] = pos.apply(rowIndex, axis=1)
print(pos)
```

Output

```
       id pred   flag
1  [4, 4]  NaN   True
2     [2]  NaN  False
3  [2, 4]  NaN   True
4     [2]  NaN  False
5  [2, 4]  NaN   True
6     [4]  NaN   True
```

Comment: You can make this more idiomatic by using `pos.index.isin()` instead of `row.name in` inside `pos.apply`, just like the other answers: `pos['flag'] = ~pos.index.isin(unique_id_values)`